# ZFS: RAIDZ and RAIDZ2 usable size?

Tags: storage, zfs, raidz

Is the usable size of a RAIDZ array similar to the [usable size of a RAID5 array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid5#RAID_5_usable_size)?

The RAID5 calculation is "(N-1) * S", where S is the size of smallest drive. Since most people use the same sized disk in a RAID5 array, this comes out to be "N-1" for most purposes.

Is RAIDZ also "(N-1) * Smin" ?

Similarly, RAID6 is (N-2) * S. Is the usable size of RAIDZ2 similar to RAID6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for RAIDZ(1) use the same formula as for RAID5. for RAIDZ2 - the same as for RAID6

Answer (score 0):

To complement the accepted answer, a calculator:

[Raid Calculator | Raid Disk Space Utilization Calculator | ServeTheHome](http://www.servethehome.com/raid-calculator/)

> RAID5 uses one disk for Parity and requires at least three drives to be used.

…

> RAID-Z uses one disk for Parity much like RAID5 and requires at least three drives to be used.

…

> RAID-Z2 uses two disks for Parity and requires at least four drives to be used.

…

> RAID-Z3 uses three disks for Parity and requires at least five drives to be used.

… and so on.